# django не стартует сервер

Tags: python, django

только начала изучать джанго. по видеоурокам сделал все пошагово. когда зупускаю сервер через кмд в ответ в конце приходит:

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.

в чем проблема?

Comment: В изучении по видеоурокам.

Comment: Предоставьте код, где подключаете все

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте свои шаблоны на наличие операторов `include`, которые указывают на несуществующие модули или модули, которые не имеют члена `urlpatterns`.

Answer (score 0):

В файле urls.py неправильно настроены ссылки на страницу, скорее всего. Вот здесь понятно объясняется, как настроить пути: https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/ru/django_urls/